# How do I display a PDF file in an InfoPath form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

How do I display a PDF file or Word document in an InfoPath form? I want to have a task assigned where the user has to read the document and sign off after reading it.

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath supports rich text fields. Unless the document is extremely complex you can simply paste the contents in such a field.

Alternatively, InfoPath supports attachments. You can attach any document, even multiple ones, and instruct the user to click on the attachment to open it in the native application.